# mixare- remove/disable other data sources

Tags: android, mobile, augmented-reality

I am trying to remove some of the data sources in mixare so that it will just automatically load the data from a specific data source when the app starts. I have tried setting them to false in my arrays.xml file:

```
<string-array name="defaultdatasources">
    <item>
            Wikipedia|http://ws.geonames.org/findNearbyWikipediaJSON|0|0|true
        </item>
    <item>
            Twitter|http://search.twitter.com/search.json|2|0|false
        </item>
        <item>
            OpenStreetmap|http://open.mapquestapi.com/xapi/api/0.6/node[railway=station]|3|1|false
       </item>
    <item>
            Own URL|http://mixare.org/geotest.php|4|0|false
        </item>
</string-array>
```

Is that the proper way to do it? I still get

> "Received data from Twitter/OSM/Own URL"

notifications plus tweets/OSM data loaded on my screen.

I am exploring the codes and I seem to get stuck on this one. Help, please? :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to restrict the pre-defined data sources in Mixare. You need to do that within the code. Not from the layouts. There is a Data Loader in Mixare. There you can comment out what ever the data sources that you don't need. You might need to edit 
org.mixare.data.DataSrouce.java class